# How extract data from qwebengineview qt5.9

Tags: c++, qt

I have a simple web page and i want to extract the text My First Heading.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">

//This is a single line comment

/* This is a
block comment */

</script>
<body>

<h1 id="title">My First Heading</h1>
<p  id="text">My first paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The page loads fine but i the runJavascript function does not return anything. 
I have tried different variations. My expected debug output should be My First Heading. What am i missing?

```
 QString path("C:\\Temp\\x.html");
 QFile file(path);
 QString source;
 file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
 source = file.readAll();
 file.close();

 page = new QWebEnginePage();
 page->load(QUrl::fromLocalFile(path));
 ui->widget->setPage(page);
 ui->widget->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::NoContextMenu);

 //page->runJavaScript("document.getElementById(title)", [](const QVariant&result){ qDebug() << result.toString();});

//page->runJavaScript("document.getElementById(\"title\")", [](const QVariant&result){ qDebug() << result.toString();});

//page->runJavaScript("document.getElementById('title')", [](const QVariant&result){ qDebug() << result.toString();});
```

Comment: If you try to get a string from the element ? Like `document.getElementById('title').text` for example ?

Comment: I tried that i get js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null

Comment: Not sure if it's that, but there is `QWebEnginePage::load` and `QWebEnginePage::setHtml` maybe you need to use the second one to set the actual content of the page ...

Comment: The property is textContent, not text, i.e.
`document.getElementById('title').textContent`
Not sure if that's the problem though.

Comment: I gave up on this i just used qtdomdocument and just used the qwebviewengine for display.

Comment: You can't call JS function until the DOM is ready, wait for the 'loadFinished' signal, check that 'load' flag is true and then run your JS function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says there is a signal emitted when the page contents have been loaded completely :[`loadFinished`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#loadFinished). 
So I think you should connect this signal to a custom slot, and only after this slot has been called will you be able to access the page's content.

Comment: thanks for your help guys. It works now i connected the load finished to a custom slow and used document.getElementById('title').textContent